asをなるべく使いたくないが、回避方法がわからない
やりたいこと
type PrimitiveType = string | number | boolean;
type ObjectType = { [K in string]: PrimitiveType };
type KV = { [K in string]: PrimitiveType | ObjectType };

type AAA = {
     min: number;
     max: number;
}

type Test1 = {
     name: string;
     age: number;
     aaa: AAA;
}

type Test2 = {
     lang: string;
     bool: boolean;
     aaa: AAA;
}

現在、上記のようなKV型のオブジェクトを管理するものを作っています。
このオブジェクトを管理するものとして以下のようなプログラムを組みました。
type KeysOfType<T, U> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends U ? K : never }[keyof T];

class KVStorage<T extends KV> {
    private key;

    constructor(key: string) {
        this.key = key;
    }

    async get(): Promise<T> {
        const obj = await browser.storage.local.get(this.key);
        if (Object.entries(obj).length === 0) {
            throw new Error(`error`);
        }
        return obj[this.key];
    }

    async getItem<U>(key: KeysOfType<T, U>): Promise<U> {
        const kv = await this.get();
        return kv[key] as U;
    }

    ...
}

getItemに注目していただきたいのですが、
return kv[key] as U;

にて、as U をしないとエラーが発生してしまいます。
KeysOfTypeで型Uの値をもつプロパティ名を取得することで、kv[key]の型がUに確定するのかと思っていましたが、どうも確定されませんでした。
このような場合、asを使うしかないのでしょうか。
もし、改善案や間違っている箇所などあれば指摘していただきたいです。
よろしくお願いします。
